# Not able to fetch phone number from Zomato API

Tags: ios, zomato-api

I am not able to fetch phone number of restaurant using `Zomato API`. Do we need to Partner with `Zomato` then only it will provide such details. I also want restaurant other details such as its website(if any provided).

Comment: According to their documentation you can fetch the details you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partner access is required to fetch restaurant's phone numbers whereas the restaurant's website information is not yet supported by the Zomato API for both basic and partner users. Find out the supported data – https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/restaurant_0